# index.php is always displayed before any file on the URL

Tags: permalinks

When I make click at any file from my website, the URL displays like:

**www.mywebsite.com/index.php/about-me** OR **www.mywebsite.com/index.php/references**

I just want to know if it is normal that index.php gets always displayed before any other file (something like **www.mywebsite.com/about-me** would be more common to see) or if this is some type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if you have an .htaccess file with the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If this file already exists with the appropriate rules, try the following:

- Go to your site Settings > Permalinks. If there is something already there, make sure you copy it and keep it safe in case it breaks your site.  Select one of the defaults and save.
- Visit your site and refresh.
- If you still have no solution, try a hard refresh on your site - `cmd/ctrl + shift + r`.

If you are still having the problem, please go into more detail about the circumstances of your site (version, plugins, theme, etc.) so we can try to better help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to do this immediately. So, my site shouldn't display the index.php, right?

Comment: Already fixed the the problem. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of @feelinferrety I was able to put the URLs from my website as **www.mywebsite.com/index.php/about-me** OR **www.mywebsite.com/index.php/references**. 
Just did the following:

Go to your site Settings > Permalinks > Common settings:  Select the option Postname.